# Database Transaction with two Databases - is this method correct?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

I have a situation in which I have 2 databases.

Manager has Companies Table, based on this value I have to create a new DB.

So I am using TransactionScope. I want to know is the following correct?

Will this roll back both changes? In both DB's if error occurs?

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
{
    try
    {
        using(var ManagerContext = new ManagerEntities(
            ConnectionStringManager.GetManagerConnectionString()))
        {
            //Operations on Manager DB                         
            // Create new Company and get NEWCOMPANYID 
            // -- Used to create new DB
        }

        using(var companyContext = new CompanyEntities(
            ConnectionStringManager.GetCompanyConnectionString(
                NEWCOMPANYID.ToString())))
        {
            //Create New Company DB
        }

        ts.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ts.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: The try-catch is redundant, since the `using` statement already ensures the disposal for the `TransactionScope`.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. I have do the ts.Dispose() if any error occurs in the try{} block

Comment: This will work if the distributed transaction coordinator is activated (for example, see http://www.luisrocha.net/2011/08/managing-transactions-with-entity.html)

Comment: @Matten even though I am using two seperate DbContext scopes I have to activate Distributed Transaction?

Comment: @DawoodAwan no, you do not need to `Dispose()` - that is exactly what `using` does: it sets up a `try`/`finally` that calls `Dispose()` on `ts` (if it is non-null).

Comment: Okay. So I am doing the development on my PC, but DB is on server. Do I have to start Distributed Transaction on my PC and the Server? Or just PC?

Comment: @DawoodAwan for that to work as a distributed transaction, all 3 must be able to talk via DTC to each-other - see "dtcping"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as both those database contexts are `TransactionScope` aware, and don't explicitly have ambient transaction enlisting disabled (in the connection string, for example), then yes: that should work fine. If we assume that the two connection strings are different, this will *definitely* require a distributed transaction (DTC), though - whether that is OK is up to you. If the connection strings are identical, you might get away with the LTM instead (less overhead / configuration).

Note that as per the comments - you don't need the `try`/`finally`.

Comment: Have you got a link to a step by step tutorial on how to activate DTC for Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: @Dawood no, but Google probably does

Comment: One final question. Does TransactionScopr Rollbak, T-SQL Scripts that are executed in the Scope. e.g. I Have a T-SQL Script to generate Tables and Stored Procedures, If that script fails will it roolback all this?

Comment: @DawoodAwan yes, it a `TransactionScope` is disposed before `Complete()` is called, that counts as a rollback. As per the caveat in my answer - yes, that will rollback the database state as long as the connections didn't explicitly opt out of ambient transactions. Note that some things *cannot* be rolled back (`xp_sendmail`, for example)

Comment: hmmmmmm. Thanks for the help. This really helped me. Now I think I can implement what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

This is OK, although it will trigger DTC as explained by Marc. You can avoid DTC by using a single `SqlConnection` (or `EntityConnection`) that both contexts share. You can switch the current database of a connection with `ChangeDatabase`. This avoids the need for distributed transactions.

You also need to open the connection explicitly because EF by default opens and closed it for every action. That causes multiple DTC enlistments (more than 2). This is a design flaw in EF.

Comment: It sounds like the LTM (rather than DTC) should still be able to be used in that scenario. However, I don't plan on trying to check

Comment: I found it is non-deterministic whether you require DTC or not. If the 2nd connection happens to be the same underlying pool connection as the first one, you don't need DTC. If it happens to be different, it triggers DTC. You typically find that mistake only under load in production. Horrible design choice.